# delete selected item from text item

Tags: forms, oracle, oracleforms

i have got multi lined text item like gridview in my forms project. i want to select an item and click delete button and the system must delete selected index but i didnt find the perfect function. it's not bind into the database so its not complicated i just want to delete the line from the text item. i tried to find the properties of the current record, i use some of loops but it didnt find the selected item index. does it have "selected item" function like c#, java. Or do i have to create a function to find selected item. which way is the best and how could i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help you(I didn't get a chance to test this) :

```
GO_BLOCK('Gridview_BLOCK_NAME');
GO_RECORD(record_index);
DELETE_RECORD;
GO_ITEM('block.delete_button');--if you want the cursor back to delete button
```